# Storing agent coordinates in a list in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a simple simulation of agents moving randomly but avoiding certain obstacles.  I want them to store the coordinates of the places they've been so they don't go there again.  This is part of what I have so far:

```
to move-agent

  let move random 3
  if (move = 0) []
  if (move = 1)[ left-turn ]
  if (move = 2)[ right-turn ]

  set xint int xcor  ;;here i'm storing the coordinates as integers
  set yint int ycor

  set xylist (xint) (yint)

  go-forward

end

to xy_list
  set xy_list []
  set xy_list fput 0 xy_list ;;populating new list with 0
end
```

However, it keeps giving me a "SET expected 2 inputs" error.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are incorrectly using `xy_list` as both a variable and a turtle variable.

I don't see the need for the xy_list procedure - Keep it as a turtle variable. Make sure xy_list is in the turtles-own list:

`turtles-own [xy_list]`

initialize it to an empty list when you create a turtle. eg:

`crt 1 [set xy_list []]`

When a turtle moves, you could add their current position as an xcor, ycor list with:

```
set xy_list fput (list int xcor int ycor) xy_list
```

You will then need to check if that coordinate already exists in the list before moving there.

However, as you are using integer coordinates, it would be a lot easier to use a patch-set to keep track of a turtle's history. You could try this:

```
turtles-own [history]

to setup
  ca
  crt 3 [set history (patch-set patch-here) pd]
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    let candidates neighbors with [not member? self [history] of myself]
    ifelse any? candidates 
      [move-to one-of candidates stamp
       set history (patch-set history patch-here)]
      [die]   
  ]
end
```